# Convert name value to JSON object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to convert below array  of name-value pair to JSON object.

Input

```
Data = [ {"name":"aaa", "value":111},{"name":"bbb", "value":222}]
```

Expected output

```
Data = {"aaa":111, "bbb":222}
```

I tried using below approach. It works but do we have any better way.

```
convertToJson(arr){
    var obj = {};
    _.each(arr,function(ar){
        obj[ar.name]= ar.value;
    });

    return obj;
}
```

Comment: That's a JavaScript object, not a JSON object. This is a pretty trivial task and there are several approaches you could take. What have you tried? Have you even thought about how you might approach the problem?

Comment: @quentin - Added the approach i tried

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce?v=example) method to reduce into a single object.

```js
var Data = [{
  "name": "aaa",
  "value": 111
}, {
  "name": "bbb",
  "value": 222
}];

var res = Data
  // itertae over the array
  .reduce(function(obj, o) {
    // defince the object property based on array element
    obj[o.name] = o.value;
    // return object reference
    return obj;
    // set initial value as an empty object
  }, {});

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var myObj = {};

for(var i = 0 ; i < Data.length ; i++){
     myObj[Data[i].name] = Data[i].value
}
```

Now myObj will have your preferred output.